# Cannot invoke changes in form a second time

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I try to write an app where I need to use a scanner via COM-port.
I'm using an enabled SerialPort object for it,
scanning works fine in the main form.

I then use a button to toggle if the main form should be able to do the `ReadExisting()` method.

```
private void ScannerDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
try
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();`
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(indata))
    {
        return;
    }
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { cbValues.SelectedItem = values; }));
}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error($"{ex}");
    }
}
```

(cbValues is a ComboBox)
(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort)

In my mainform I use this to create a new form:

```
var form = new Form2(_data, scanner);
form.ShowDialog();
```

Then the form is shown as expected.
On the first try when I scan stuff in the new form everything works fine.

Then I close the 'child' form.

Then I reopen it and it is shown and the scanner event is fired.

This is my constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
HandleCreated += new EventHandler((sender, args) =>
{
    scanner.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ScannerDataReceivedHandler);
});
```

In my event I try to invoke a change in a combobox.

```
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { cbValues.SelectedItem = values; }));
```

On my second try the form is not created (IsCreated = false) and doesn't have a handle (IsHandleCreated = false), despite being visible AND reacting to the scanner.

I cannot wrap my head around it. I also tried `using` the form to have it disposed after usage, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a guess?

Comment: You are referencing code we cannot see.  `ReadExisting()`  `IsCreated` `IsHandleCreated`?  We probably need to see a bit more complete code example.

Comment: @LarsTech does this help? IsCreated and IsHandleCreated are standard values of WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
It is ugly, but it works.
I hope there will be a future me with a nice solution.
The solution: closing the `SerialPort` object via `scanner.Close()` and opening it in the other form.
After everything is scanned closing that object on `Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 0):

I read your post and code carefully. As I understand it, `scanner` is a member variable of `MainForm`, and you're passing it as an argument to the `Form2` constructor. More than a guess, what I'm seeing is a roundabout way to subscribe to the event that *should* be attached *in the main form* one time as soon as the `scanner` is instantiated.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        scanner = new Scanner();
        scanner.DataReceived += ScannerDataReceivedHandler;
    }
    // F O R    E X A M P L E
    // The class name `Scanner` is just a placeholder for this example.
    // The point is, it's being declared/instantiated "somewhere".
    private readonly Scanner scanner;
    private void ScannerDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to handle it more cleanly instead of messing with timers and variables. Is there a clean solution for that possible? Any tips are appreciated...

Comment: Timers and variables? I'm sorry - I don't understand (because I don't see anything about timers or variables in your question or in my answer).

Comment: Is this a USB barcode scanner by the way?

Comment: Indeed it is, timers and variables was an idea, but I've updated my answer how I solved it (for now).

Comment: Can you try making a [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/barcode-scanner-01.git) of my USB barcode-QR-code scanner and see if it works for you? I'm real curious.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I will try it at the end of the week, we have some urgent tasks replacing tons of hardware...